# How to use Mutate/Convert in logstash config file for nested fields in Json file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, dplyr

I have below JSON as input to logstash.

```
{  
   "totalTurnoverUSD":11111.456,
   "children":[  
      {  
         "totalTurnoverUSD":11100.456,
         "children":[  
            {  
               "totalTurnoverUSD":11.00,
               "children":[  

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

And using below config file to output that to elasticSearch and stdout.

```
input {  
    file {
        type => $type 
        path => $filePathofJsonFile 
        codec => "json" 
        start_position => "beginning" 
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null" 
        ignore_older => 0 
        close_older => 2 
        max_open_files => 10
    }
}
filter {
    mutate {
        convert => { "totalTurnoverUSD" => "string" } 
    }
}

output { 
    elasticsearch{ 
        hosts => $elasticHost 
        index =>"123" 
    } 
    stdout { 
    codec => rubydebug 
    } 
}
```

But getting below error message

```
"error"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"mapper [children.totalTurnoverUSD] of different type, current_type [long], merged_type [double]"}}}, :level=>:warn}
```

because I am not converting totalTurnoverUSD field in the nested children document of JSON input file.

So, is there any way available to access nested fields in the JSON document for mutating them to converts their datatype to String.

Comment: Do you know how many nested levels you have? Is it always three? or three max?

Comment: no it is not always three. It can be upto any level.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to let Logstash send whatever numeric type of `totalTurnoverUSD` it comes up with, but then to use an [dynamic template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch) in Elasticsearch.

You can modify your index like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "full_name": {
            "path_match":   "*.totalTurnoverUSD",
            "mapping": {
              "type":       "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What this is going to achieve is that whenever indexing any document into that index, any field named `totalTurnoverUSD` at any level in the document, will get the type `keyword`.

You might need to delete your index first and recreate it from scratch, but try it out without deleting it first.

**UPDATE**

if you want to apply this to all your indices, you can create an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) like this:

```
PUT _template/all_indices
{
  "template": "*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "full_name": {
            "path_match":   "*.totalTurnoverUSD",
            "mapping": {
              "type":       "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As a result, all mapping type in all indices will get the dynamic template for `totalTurnoverUSD`

Comment: Yes. First need to delete all indexes and then after adding dynamic mapping recreating of indexing works. Do you know how to put dynamic mapping for all indexes in elastic search?

Comment: Yes, instead of `my_type` use `_default_`, but you still need to PUT this in all your indices... or use an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) that gets applied on each index creation

Comment: And what's about my_index value next to PUT word?

Comment: Thanks for your help :) appreciated. i will try it now.